# interate over python pandas dataframe from last row to first

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with statistical data that is cumulated with each new row. Every day a new row is added. Now I want to iterate over my column so that each row (starting from last) is substracted from the row above. The new value should be put into a new column.
This is how my dataframe looks and the values in the column 'diff' are my desired outcome:

```
     time        In     diff
0  2017-06-26  7.086      
1  2017-06-27  8.086     1
2  2017-06-28  10.200    2.114
```

this is what I came up with:

```
for x in df['In']:
    df['diff'] = df.iloc[-1] - df.iloc[-2]
```

but thats not it. How do I start the loop from the last row and how do I make the iloc more dynamic? Can someone help?
thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['diff'] = df['In'].diff()
print (df)
         time      In   diff
0  2017-06-26   7.086    NaN
1  2017-06-27   8.086  1.000
2  2017-06-28  10.200  2.114
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.Series.diff`

```
df.assign(Diff=df.In.diff())
```

Comment: I dont understand your post. I think whats missing here is a new column. But when I try df['diff'] = df.assign(Diff=df.In.diff()) i get an ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 11, placement implies 1

Comment: @Burray assign creates a copy of original dataframe with a new column. Use: df = df.assign(Diff=df.In.diff())

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `shift()`:

```
df
       In        time
0   7.086  2017-06-26
1   8.086  2017-06-27
2  10.200  2017-06-28


df.sort_values('time', inplace=True)

df['diff'] = df['In'] - df['In'].shift(1)

df
       In       time   diff
0   7.086 2017-06-26    NaN
1   8.086 2017-06-27  1.000
2  10.200 2017-06-28  2.114
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is all you need to do.

```
 df['diff'] = df.In - df.In.shift(1)

 # In [16]: df
 # Out[16]:
 #        time      In   diff
 # 0  2017-06-26   7.086    NaN
 # 1  2017-06-27   8.086  1.000
 # 2  2017-06-28  10.200  2.114
```